# Dlink DWL-G120 Windows 7 driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Does anyone know if out there is a driver for D-Link DWL-G120 on Windows 7. I searched everywhere and couldn't find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the device has already been discontinued and there no available driver update, you will have hard time installing this device to Vista or Windows 7.

Nevertheless, this thread claims it's possible : [Running Vista Beta 2 (x86 build)--DWL-G120 drivers?](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/231444-35-running-vista-beta-build-g120-drivers).
The instructions are for Vista, which is entirely compatible with Windows 7.
However, don't expect this to work if you are running Windows 7 64-bit.

> 1. Click here to download [these drivers](ftp://ftp.dlink.co.uk/wireless/dwl-g120/dwl-g120_drv_v200.zip) (this version is a little
>      newer then the one on the U.S. site)
> 2. Right-click on the setup file
> 3. Click on properties
> 4. Click on the compatibility tab & set it to Windows XP (Service Pack 2)
> 5. Then click on the security tab & change it to administrator access
> 6. Install it
>
> Once it's done installing, use windows
>   to select the network.

Another guy on the same thread said:

> The D-Link DWL-G120 **Revision B1** is
>   compatible with 32-bit Vista. The
>   latest 3.00 drivers are on [D-Link
>   Taiwan's site](http://tsd.dlink.com.tw/ModelDocu.asp?SourceType=download&sno=NSNTBN). Extract the
>   archive, use Vista's Device Manager,
>   select the device (probably shown as
>   Unknown Device), and then use Update
>   Driver and navigate to the Drivers
>   folder of the downloaded driver. Do
>   not use the setup.exe file bundled
>   with the driver. This driver also
>   gives the adapter WPA security.

In my case the Taiwanese site timed-out, but you might have better luck than me.

Comment: I came across this, but wasn't sure to post it or not as an answer. Regardless, the Taiwanese was working fine for me, and I've mirrored the drivers here https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpnfnmwu66l73ub/DWL-G120_C1_Driver%20v3-00_050110.rar

Comment: Thanks a lot. We're very happy here in Poland. The first solution made it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to install just fine in Windows 7 and it works very well. Download the 3.0 drivers from the Taiwanese site, do an install using XP SP2 compatibility, reboot, and then plug it in. The utility won't work, but windows will configure and use the card properly. You can use a program like WinPatrol to remove the D-Link utility from the startup.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the DWL-G120 was discontinued in 2007, it's unlikely you're going to find drivers. Microsoft also states that it is [incompatible with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=D-Link%20DWL-G120%20High%20Speed%202.4GHz%20802.11g%20Wireless%20Network%20Adapter&v=D-Link&uid=DWL-G120&l=en-US&pf=10&pi=3&s=network%20adapter&os=64-bit).

Comment: That's what I also found